# Counting empty relations from a SQL table

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

I'm trying to count authors who don't have any articles in our system, which aggregates authorship across sites. I've got a query working, but it isn't performant.

The best query I have thus far is this:

```
select count(*) as count_all
from (
  select authors.id
  from authors
  left outer join site_authors on site_authors.author_id = authors.id
  left outer join articles on articles.site_author_id = site_authors.id
  group by authors.id
  having count(articles.id) = 0
) a;
```

However, the subquery is rather inefficient. I was hoping there's a way to flatten this. I have several similar queries that add extra conditions on the left outer joins, so adding a count column to my schema isn't really an option here.

Extra rub: this is a cross-platform query and needs to work against both pgSQL, SQLite, and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a little bit different query, but I'm not sure that it will be faster:

```
select count(*)
from authors as a
where not exists (
    select b.id
    from site_authors as b
        inner join
    articles as c
    on a.id=b.author_id and b.id=c.site_author_id)
```

of course I suppose you have proper indexes on tables:

- site_authors: unique (author_id, id)
- articles: non unique (site_author_id)

Comment: It wil not be slower. (verifying that smomething does not exist is cheaper than counting tuples and comparing the result to zero)

Comment: Yeah, PG is showing it as being about twice as slow. The cost of the original query is approx 106, with no subplan. Your suggestion gives it a cost of 214, with a subplan.

Comment: @SEK is this with indexes built and stas gathered/rebuild?

Comment: yep. indexes on all the foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'normal' joins are simpler and faster, you could subtract the number of authors with articles from the total number of authors:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM authors) -
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT site_authors.author_id)
        FROM site_authors
        JOIN articles ON articles.site_author_id = site_authors.id)
```

Alternatively, try a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM authors
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT site_authors.author_id
                 FROM site_authors
                 JOIN articles ON articles.site_author_id = site_authors.id)
```

Comment: The former might be a good idea, but the approach doesn't work well for my other queries, such as authors that haven't published any articles in the last month

Comment: The first approach seems promising, but depends on getting it to use indexed joins efficiently. For example, there are far many more site_authors than authors, so it's better to do an inner join on authors rather than distinct. When I tested it out with that extra inner join, it dropped the cost from 10k to 112, just 6 more than my original query. On the other hand, I already query the full count, so I might be able to tune this so it does more work on the application side

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler and faster to use NOT IN rather than a join.  Sql processors are pretty smart about using indexes even when it looks obtuse.  Something like this:

```
Select count(*)
  from authors
 where id not in (select author_id from site_authors)
   and id not in (select site_author_id from articles);
```

Be sure that author_id and site_author_id are indexed.  The optimizer will notice what your are doing and create an indexed look up for the "NOT IN" clause.

Comment: That won't work. authors.id is not the fk for site_author_id. it would need to do a subquery against an inner join of site_authors/articles. However, that might be more efficient. I'll give it a shot and see if the numbers work.

Comment: ahh yes.  I didn't notice that indirection.  The not in clause could apply to a select/join.  Now I'm curious.  Let me know.

Comment: Much less efficient. PG didn't pick it up as an indexed not in